# Why are my "tools" stuck to the origin?

Tags: transforms

I am a Blender noob with a (hopefully) quick question. When I move, translate, or scale an object, the tools used to interact with it do not move with it, and instead remain stuck at 0,0,0: [image: Text] What did I do to make this happen, and how can I change it back?

Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You've set your "Transform Pivot Point" to "3D cursor." Change it back to the default "Median Point"

Comment: Awesome! I must have messed that up playing with snapping. Blender is difficult to work with, but helpful folks like you make it much easier!